# Numerically representing the direction of a vector given its components

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've been learning Linear Algebra and I'm having trouble translating the given representations into terms of the direction of the vector. It doesn't appear to be given as part of the representation?

Excuse my ad-hoc representation, but this is about what I'm given:

[badly drawn vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgoWc.png)

What am I missing? Are there even directions for vectors like this?

Comment: "Direction" is not a property that all vectors share.  The vectors that have inherent directions are *translation* (AKA *Euclidean*) vectors -- these are the vectors that we draw as arrows. Once you've chosen a *basis* of Euclidean space, say $\{\hat e_1, \hat e_2, \dots, \hat e_n\}$, then every vector in that space can be expanded in that basis: $\vec v = v_1\hat e_1 + \cdots + v_n\hat e_n$. There's a natural bijection from this space (with this particular basis) to the space of $n\times 1$ matrices that maps this vector to $\pmatrix{v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n}$.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still struggling to understand - how can you determine what the direction is from a horizontal vector?

Comment: Well you'd have to decide how you want to describe direction.  Perhaps you'd like to describe it by the unique parametrized line through the origin that shares that direction.  Or you could simply find the unique unit vector in the direction of your horizontal vector.  Or you might just consider the word "horizontal" to be enough to specify the direction of your vector.  When talking about the intuitive notion of *direction* you have to decide for yourself what would be a good way to describe it.

Comment: Ah, okay. So there is no standard direction applied to every vector, and it's more determined by the model/representation/space?

Comment: If I understand you right, then yes.  Direction is something that not all vectors have, and the ones that *do* have a specific direction, *you're* the one who decides which directions are important enough to specify all other directions from them (on Earth for instance, North, South, East, and West are pretty useful for that, but nothing says those *have* to be our reference directions).

Comment: And that would be represented separately to the horizontal vector? So you would have the horizontal vector, and then a direction vector/angle/whatever.

Comment: Basically if you've got a space of vectors that have a property that you might call *direction*, then you pick a basis for that space and all other directions are considered in terms of that basis (like $38$ degrees East of North when talking about directions on Earth).

Comment: Thank you. The way you've worded your explanations has helped me with more than just this problem. Appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the resident of a plane say "that way" mathematically? Rember that the **unit circle** is defined as the circle with center at the origin and radius of $1$. If you were standing at the center of this circle and pointed in any direction, you would be pointing at a point on the unit circle. This can be generalized to a "unit sphere" in n-dimensional space.

That corresponds mathematically to a vector with initial point at the origin and terminal point at the point on the unit sphere that you had just indicated. Notice that the length of this vector must be $1$. in general, "direction" can be indicated by a vector of length $1$, that is, a unit vector.

So if your vector, $\vec v,$ had a length $|\vec v| \ne 0$, its direction would be the unit vector $\vec u = \dfrac{1}{|\vec v|}\vec v$ and its length would be $ |\vec v| = \sqrt{\sum v_i^2}$.

Comment: Ah, so direction is typically determined based on the unit sphere/circle? That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of a vector (except those with length $0$) is a vector as well, one with length $1$:
$$
x_d = \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert} x
$$
Or written the other way
$$
x = \lVert x \rVert \, x_d
$$
shows the decomposition of the vector into length and direction vector.

E.g. using the norm $\lVert x \rVert^2 = x \cdot x$ with the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and having
$$
u = 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
0\\
0 \\
-4
\end{array}
\right]
$$
One gets
$$
x_d = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{0^2+0^2+(-4)^2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
0\\
0 \\
-4
\end{array}
\right]
= 
\frac{1}{4}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0 \\
-4
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
0\\
0 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
that vector points in negative $z$-direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. These representations in terms of horizontal vectors have been very useful.

Comment: So, the direction here is simply shown as a smaller version of the vector?

Comment: Horizontal means along the horizon, these components above are vertical aligned (column vectors).

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I am getting mixed up with terminology quite a bit.

Comment: All vectors of the same direction have $x = \alpha \,x_d$ for positive $\alpha$, they differ just in length. You could use any vector of the set as representant of that set, the one with length $1$ is a convenient one.